# Transformers cannot loop over list elements

Tags: esb, designer, webmethods

I am trying to figure out with ESB. Software Ag Designer.
I am getting error. [image] 
Transformers cannot loop over list elements. 
When I am doing transform.

Please help.

Comment: can you share the exact error/error dump that you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentList that you are trying to calculate the size of `relatedPartyRef` is a part of another Document List `requestedTimeSlot`. Please loop over the first DocumentList `requestedTimeSlot` and find the size of child DocumentList inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly in your screenshot, in your "sizeOfList" transformer you are not getting the reference to the *single* "requestedTimeSlot" item in the loop, but to the whole "searchTimeSlot/requestedTimeSlot[]" array (notice the difference in the icons between your screenshot and the example below).
Try removing the map step containing the transformer and adding it back again. If that does not help, maybe you need to install the latest fixes for your version.
[Example of mapping in nested loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8WCB.png)

hope this helps